# Get earliest date from dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started working with DataFrames and i'm struggling with a request:

I have a df with this structure:

```
id req_date             spec_date
1  2021-09-28T07:19:43  2021-09-24T07:17:02
2  2021-04-28T07:19:43  
3                       2021-02-21T07:14:41
```

I'm trying to create a new column for which the values to be the earliest dates between the req_date and spec_date. It's working as expected when both column have values , but if one of them is empty then the new column value will also be empty, how do i treat this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) along columns with `skipna=False`

```py
df['col'] = (df[['req_date', 'spec_date']]
             .apply(pd.to_datetime)
             .min(axis=1, skipna=False)
             .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
)
```

```
print(df)

   id             req_date            spec_date                  col
0   1  2021-09-28T07:19:43  2021-09-24T07:17:02  2021-09-24T07:17:02
1   2  2021-04-28T07:19:43                 None                  NaN
2   3                 None  2021-02-21T07:14:41                  NaN
```

Depending if you want to skip `NAN`, you can adjust `skipna`

```py
df['col'] = (df[['req_date', 'spec_date']]
             .apply(pd.to_datetime)
             .min(axis=1)   # <-- difference here
             .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
)
```

```
print(df)

   id             req_date            spec_date                  col
0   1  2021-09-28T07:19:43  2021-09-24T07:17:02  2021-09-24T07:17:02
1   2  2021-04-28T07:19:43                 None  2021-04-28T07:19:43
2   3                 None  2021-02-21T07:14:41  2021-02-21T07:14:41
```

Comment: In case one of columns is empty , i want to have the value from the column that has value not NaN, so in row will be 2021-04-28T07:19:43.

Comment: @coLby See the update, remove `skipna` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for minimum of two dates, you could substitute missing values
with technical date like '9999-12-31T00:00:00'. It will make further comparison easier (no need for handling with or checking nulls).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

# generating a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2021-09-28T07:19:43', '2021-09-24T07:17:02'],
                   [2, '2021-04-28T07:19:43', None],
                   [3, None, '2021-02-21T07:14:41']],
                  columns=['id', 'req_date', 'spec_date'])

# printing content of dataframe
print(df)

df['req_date'] = df['req_date'].fillna('9999-12-31T00:00:00')
df['spec_date']= df['spec_date'].fillna('9999-12-31T00:00:00')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

While [@Ynjxsjmh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086451/16343464) is the cleanest way to go, you could also take advantage of your date format that can be sorted as string to get the min without conversion.

First `fillna` with a string that will sort after a number, for example `'NaT'` (or `'X'`), then get the `min`:

```
df['min'] = df[['req_date', 'spec_date']].fillna('NaT').min(axis=1)
```

If you already have empty strings use `replace` instead:

```
df['min'] = df[['req_date', 'spec_date']].replace('', 'NaT').min(axis=1)
```

output:

```
   id             req_date            spec_date                  min
0   1  2021-09-28T07:19:43  2021-09-24T07:17:02  2021-09-24T07:17:02
1   2  2021-04-28T07:19:43                  NaN  2021-04-28T07:19:43
2   3                  NaN  2021-02-21T07:14:41  2021-02-21T07:14:41
```